# Qt VS2015 projects load Error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.7

Just (30.08.2016) got Qt *dev*-branch, compiled with *nmake* and got libraries.

But when I create the VS2015 projects (*qmake -tp vc -recursive qt.pro*) and try to open them, VS2015 states an exception while loading:

> F:\dev\env64\Qt5\qtbase\examples\gui\analogclock\analogclock.vcxproj :
>   error  : An exception was thrown while initializing part
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator".

Does anyone has similar errors? And is there an solution?

Comment: Looks like qmake output is a good testcase for a MSVC bug, then :) Looks like a MSVC bug, but perhaps the qmake output is not perfect.

Comment: Hi, currently I found an error within the generated VS-project files. It seems that qmake tries to include a CustomBuild step into project files. (Not a good idea anyway). Additionally qmake does that even with _-nomoc_ flag. - Both clear issues for qmake.

Comment: These are supposed to work - and they did work up until very recently. Perhaps MSVC regressed. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Good information. @Kuba Ober: Why do you think the project-integrated CustomBuild-steps should work? - I made the experience (since VS2010) only the external Customisations (.target / . prop) work. Could you give me an example of vcproj with internal Customisation or better, the msdn link describing the mechanism?